# Find number of roots of an equation

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Given $ f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{4x+3}{x^2+1}$, find how many roots the equation $$f(f(x))=\int_3^4{f(x)\mathrm{d}x}$$
> has in the interval $[1, 4]$.

Consulting GeoGebra for the graphs, there is a root in that interval. Obviously, I first tried to use the minimum/maximum on $f(x)$ in the interval and the monotonicity so as to restrict $f(f(x))$ and the integral to a common interval (The integral's interval should be a subinterval of the function's interval so the existence and uniqueness of the root would be implied by the intermediate value theorem and the function's monotonicity - it is strictly increasing.) but that hasn't worked out. I also computed the integral to be $\ln{\frac{289}{100}}+3\cot^{-1}{13}\approx 1.29$ and then $f(f(1))\approx 1.28< 1.29 < 3.32 = f(f(4))$ but these are based on approximations while I would want a not-so-computational (theoretical, as you may call it) approach, while of course leaving room for some necessary but reasonable computations (not that I would have to approximate $cot^{-1} !)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A root will be a root of the 4x+3. So $x=-3/4$. No?

Comment: @user29999  that does not reconcile with the right-hand side of OP's equation.

Comment: I think your argument is a good start and is what I would try, too.  By continuity you know there will be one solution and by monotonicity there can be only one.

Comment: The definite integral is just a number C. What you have to solve is $f(y)=C\Leftrightarrow \frac{4y+3}{y^2+1}=C$. This is a quadratic in y with at most 2 roots. Once you’ve got y you could find the x.

Comment: FWIW, if I did the algebra correctly, the LHS expands to $\frac{3x^4 + 16x^3 + 18x^2 + 16x + 15}{x^4 + 18x^2 + 24x + 10}$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem solves numerically.

1. Calculate the definite integral $C=\int_3^4{\frac{4x+3}{1+x^2}dx}$ to approximately $C\approx 1.2916$
2. Solve $f(y)=C\Rightarrow y\approx -0.38038\text{ or } y\approx 3.4773$
3. Solve $f(x)=y$ for each value of y obtained at previous step
4. Out of 4 solutions, only one is within $[1,4]: f(x)=3.4773, x\approx 1.015$